# Position Image outside of fluid centered div

Tags: css, positioning

[image]
I have a problem trying to position an image to the right of a centered div. This code works in Chrome and Safari but not IE8 or Firefox. The Chrome version is what I'm going for, not the IE version as shown in the picture. Thanks!

```
#page {
width: 90%;
max-width: 1400px;
min-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: 
white;
}

<div style="width: 90%; max-width: 1400px; min-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="float: right; position: relative; z-index: 200; bottom: 4px; left: 20px;">
    <a href="<?php echo tep_href_link('specials.php');?>"><img src="images/clearance-tab-vert.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page">
blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QLBjX/2/

```
#page {
width: 90%;
max-width: 1400px;
min-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: 
white;
}

<div id="page">
blah
<div style="float:right; background:black; width:100px; height:100px";>
<a href="<?php echo tep_href_link('specials.php');?>"><img src="images/clearance-tab-vert.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the image outside of the #page container, but next to each other? It's hard to see in the picture above.